# Load input directive by binding in Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an input like this:

```
<input type="text" valid-text class="input-text" name="{{$ctrl.name}}">
```

the key thing is the valid-text directive. This input is a component and some times is valid-text and sometimes valid-number. How can I set dynamically this value?

I tested valid-{{$ctrl.validType}} with no success.

Comment: Going to need more information, is this your valid-text / valid-number directive? What is $ctrl.validType? I would also post the relevant code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Have you seen  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern before trying to make custom directives?

Answer (score 0):

You can begin with the next directive that's get both model and attribute. Now it add both attribute `string` and number

```
myApp.directive('dynAttr', function() {
return {
    scope: { list: '=dynAttr' },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){

        for(attr in scope.list){
            elem.attr(scope.list[attr].attr, scope.list[attr].value);  
            // you can change this logic
        }

    }
};
});
```

in yours controller

```
$scope.dynAttribute = [
    { attr: 'number', value: '' },
    { attr: 'string', value: '' }
];
```

and html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="val" dyn-attr="dynAttribute"/>
</div>
```

Comment: dont know what do you mean... the input is a component itself and I put it in some parts of the application. The problem is in some parts of the code the used directive is valid-text and in the other ones is valid-number. I pass this config in the controller of the component.